# Random position of enemy

Tags: java, processing, collision

So I am trying to code a game when you dodge an enemy and the enemy goes to the end of the screen, a mini version of yourself spawn and if you or your mini you touches the enemy, the game ends. I'm currently stuck on generating random positions of the enemy after it goes to the end of the screen. Anyone has an Idea, my enemy position just keep bouncing off at the same position. And also, anyone has a clue on how to do collision detection of the main creature and the enemy. Al helps would be appreciated :( I'm a noob and dead stuck please help.

```
int PosX = 10;
int PosY = 10;
int counter = 0;
float enemyX;
float enemyY;
float speedX;
float speedY;
float creatureradius = 115;
boolean collisiondetected;



void setup(){
frameRate(60);
size(600,600); 
speedX = random(5);
speedY = random(3);

  
}

void draw(){
  background(154,206,203);
  doraemon();
  enemy();
  check();
  
  //if(collisiondetected = true){
    //gameOver();
  }

// draw the main creature
void doraemon(){
stroke(0,0,0);
fill(0,180,300); 
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,115,115); 
stroke(0,0,0);
fill(255,255,255); 
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY+10,95,95); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX-12,mouseY-40,20,30); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX+12,mouseY-40,20,30); 
fill(0,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX+7,mouseY-45,8,8); 
fill(0,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX-7,mouseY-45,8,8); 
fill(255,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY-25,15,15); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
line(mouseX,mouseY-18,mouseX,mouseY+20); 
line(mouseX-50,mouseY-18,mouseX-10,mouseY-10);
line(mouseX-55,mouseY-1,mouseX-10,mouseY);
line(mouseX-50,mouseY+17,mouseX-10,mouseY+10);
line(mouseX+55,mouseY+1,mouseX+10,mouseY);
line(mouseX+50,mouseY+16,mouseX+10,mouseY+10);
line(mouseX+50,mouseY-17,mouseX+10,mouseY-10);
fill(255,50,0); 
arc(mouseX, mouseY+20, 70, 70, 0, PI, PIE);
stroke(0);
fill(255,0,0); 
rect(mouseX-40,mouseY+55,80,10,7); 
fill(255, 247, 153);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY+60, 15, 15);
check();
}


void MiniDoraemon(){
stroke(0,0,0);
fill(0,180,300); 
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,115,115); 
stroke(0,0,0);
fill(255,255,255); 
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY+10,95,95); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX-12,mouseY-40,20,30); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX+12,mouseY-40,20,30); 
fill(0,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX+7,mouseY-45,8,8); 
fill(0,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX-7,mouseY-45,8,8); 
fill(255,0,0); 
stroke(0,0,0);
ellipse(mouseX,mouseY-25,15,15); 
fill(255,255,255); 
stroke(0,0,0);
line(mouseX,mouseY-18,mouseX,mouseY+20); 
line(mouseX-50,mouseY-18,mouseX-10,mouseY-10);
line(mouseX-55,mouseY-1,mouseX-10,mouseY);
line(mouseX-50,mouseY+17,mouseX-10,mouseY+10);
line(mouseX+55,mouseY+1,mouseX+10,mouseY);
line(mouseX+50,mouseY+16,mouseX+10,mouseY+10);
line(mouseX+50,mouseY-17,mouseX+10,mouseY-10);
fill(255,50,0); 
arc(mouseX, mouseY+20, 70, 70, 0, PI, PIE);
stroke(0);
fill(255,0,0); 
rect(mouseX-40,mouseY+55,80,10,7); 
fill(255, 247, 153);
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY+60, 15, 15);

}

  
void enemy(){
  fill(100,100,240);
  ellipse (enemyX, enemyY, 50,50);
  ellipse (enemyX, enemyY +10 , 100, 30);  
  enemymove();
  }


void enemymove(){
  outofbound();
  enemyX = enemyX+speedX;
  enemyY = enemyY+speedY;
}

void outofbound(){
  if((enemyX > width+80 || enemyX < -80) && (enemyY>height+80 || enemyY < -80)){
    random(enemyX);
    random(enemyY);
    speedX = speedX * -1;
    speedY = speedY * -1;
    
}
}

void spawnMiniDoraemon(){
  MiniDoraemon();
}

  
void distance(){
  
}





void check(){
if (dist(mouseX,mouseY,enemyX,enemyY)< 50+creatureradius){
  fill(255);
}else{
  fill(0);
}
}
  
    


  

void gameover(){
}


// Swarming effect:
int Swarm(int starting, int end){
  int fly = (end - starting)/24 + starting;
  return fly;
  

}
```

Comment: When you call random in outbound you don't assign the result to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Java is strictly pass-by-value. Thus, `random(enemyX)` makes a copy of the value of what `enemyX` *currently* holds, and passes this copy to the `random` method, which is then completely screwed and can't do the job: It can modify its copy all day long, that's not going to do anything, it is not possible to determine that you passed specifically `enemyX` (versus, say, `enemyY`), and you don't do anything with the result.

Instead, you're looking for:

```
enemyX = random();
```

Where random would be osmething like:

```
private static final Random rnd = new Random(PosX);

float random(int max) {
    return max * rnd.nextFloat();
}
```

Your code is hard to read; presumably, the playing field is defined as being between [0, PosX] for the X position and [0, PosY] for the Y position, but if that's wrong, adjust the above code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Like write @rzwitserloot your code is not clear to understand your problem. You need to write a code smaller as possible to isolate your bug or your question. But when i read the last part of your code it's possible I read `random(enemyX)`and there is problem, because with this line you generate a value with random on a range equal to `0` to `enemyX`that's it, you don't use it after. maybe you need to write something like that : `enemyX = random(enemyX)` but i'm not is what you want.

just in case a refactor allitle bit a part of your code like that... if that's can help.

```
int enemyX = 10000;
int enemyY = 10000;
int speedX = 1;
int speedY = 1;
void setup() {
  println("before ",enemyX,enemyY,speedX,speedY);
  outofbound();
  println("after ",enemyX,enemyY,speedX,speedY);
}

void outofbound() {
  int marge = 80;
  int min_x = -marge;
  int max_x = width+marge;
  int min_y = -marge;
  int max_y = width+marge;
  println("canvas",min_x,max_x,min_y, max_y);
  if((enemyX > max_x || enemyX < min_x) && (enemyY > max_y || enemyY < min_y)) {
    enemyX = (int)random(min_x, max_x);
    enemyY = (int)random(min_y, max_y);
    speedX = speedX * -1;
    speedY = speedY * -1;
  }
}
```

You can ask help here to https://discourse.processing.org/  but before that try to write a very simple code.